# Efficient way of calling set of functions in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I have a set of functions:

```
functions=set(...)
```

All the functions need one parameter x.

What is the most efficient way in python of doing something similar to:

```
for function in functions:
   function(x)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have there?

Comment: If the rules for making the set allow, I would be tempted to write a dispatch function that would make the appropriate calls in order.  That is a more explicit approach.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897362/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-invoking-a-list-of-functions-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you give,

```
for function in functions:
    function(x)
```

...does not appear to do anything with the result of calling `function(x)`. If that is indeed so, meaning that these functions are called for their side-effects, then there is no more pythonic alternative. *Just leave your code as it is.*<sup>†</sup> The point to take home here, specifically, is

**Avoid functions with side-effects in list-comprehensions.**

As for efficiency: I expect that using anything else instead of your simple loop will not improve runtime. When in doubt, use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/timeit.html). For example, the following tests seem to indicate that a regular for-loop is faster than a list-comprehension. (I would be reluctant to draw any general conclusions from this test, thought):

```
>>> timeit.Timer('[f(20) for f in functions]', 'functions = [lambda n: i * n for i in range(100)]').repeat()
[44.727972984313965, 44.752119779586792, 44.577917814254761]
>>> timeit.Timer('for f in functions: f(20)', 'functions = [lambda n: i * n for i in range(100)]').repeat()
[40.320928812026978, 40.491761207580566, 40.303879022598267]
```

But again, *even if* these tests would have indicated that list-comprehensions are faster, the point remains that you should not use them when side-effects are involved, for readability's sake.

---

<sup>†</sup>: Well, I'd write `for f in functions`, so that the difference beteen `function` and `functions` is more pronounced. But that's not what this question is about.

Comment: +1 for the "Avoid functions with side-effects in list-comprehensions" reminder.

Comment: Especially since the order of iterating over set members is not defined

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output, a list comprehension would work.

```
[func(x) for func in functions]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat doubtful of how much of an impact this will have on the total running time of your program, but I guess you could do something like this:

```
[func(x) for func in functions]
```

The downside is that you will create a new list that you immediatly toss away, but it should be slightly faster than just the for-loop.

In any case, make sure you profile your code to confirm that this really is a bottleneck that you need to take care of.

Comment: There's no particular reason that a list comprehension should be faster than the `for` loop. Such claims require benchmarks.

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops seems to indicate that there is a particular reason, namely that the loop gets pushed into compiled C code. True, there are other factors that also contribute, which is why I told him to profile.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I redid the test using timeit

My new test code:

```
import timeit

def func(i):
    return i;

a = b = c = d = e = f = func

functions = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

timer = timeit.Timer("[f(2) for f in functions]", "from __main__ import functions")
print (timer.repeat())

timer = timeit.Timer("map(lambda f: f(2), functions)", "from __main__ import functions")
print (timer.repeat())

timer = timeit.Timer("for f in functions: f(2)", "from __main__ import functions")
print (timer.repeat())
```

Here is the results from this timing.

```
testing list comprehension
[1.7169530391693115, 1.7683839797973633, 1.7840299606323242]

testing map(f, l)
[2.5285000801086426, 2.5957231521606445, 2.6551258563995361]    

testing plain loop
[1.1665718555450439, 1.1711149215698242, 1.1652190685272217]
```

My original, time.time() based timings are pretty much inline with this testing, plain for loops seem to be the most efficient.